# Partial unmarshalling with references

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm having trouble parsing the following xml :

```
<ODM xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3">
  <Study OID="CDASH_Study_2011-10-24">
    <GlobalVariables>
        <StudyName>CDASH</StudyName>
        <StudyDescription>CDASH Publication</StudyDescription>
        <ProtocolName>CDASH</ProtocolName>
    </GlobalVariables>        
    <MetaDataVersion OID="CDASH_MetaDataVersion_2011-10-24" Name="CDASH MDV">
        <FormDef OID="F.AE_2011-10-24" Name="Adverse Event" Repeating="No">
            <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="IG.AEYN_2011-10-24" Mandatory="Yes"/>
        </FormDef>
        <ItemGroupDef OID="IG.AEYN_2011-10-24" Name="General information" Repeating="No">
            <ItemRef ItemOID="AE_1_2011-10-24" Mandatory="Yes"/>
        </ItemGroupDef>
        <ItemDef OID="AE_1_2011-10-24" Name="Any AEs?" DataType="text" Length="1">
            <Description>
                <TranslatedText xml:lang="en">General prompt question...</TranslatedText>
            </Description>
            <Question>
                <TranslatedText xml:lang="en">Any AEs?</TranslatedText>
            </Question>                
            <Alias Context="CDASH" Name="AEYN"/>
        </ItemDef>
    </MetaDataVersion>
  </Study>
</ODM>
```

As you can see, the XML uses a kind of flattened tree in which FormDef elements contain ItemGroupRef elements which refer by an OID to ItemGroupDef elements stored at the same level as the FormDefs (MetaDataVersion). Of course I could parse this myself, building index maps and then linking all the generated classes together as required, however I was wondering if JAXB was capable of supporting this itself.

I would also like to unmarshal the data without creating JAXB annotated classes for the elements that I'm not interested in. In my particular case I'm only interested in the contents of the MetaDataVersion element. I tried simply unmarshalling with a FormDef class but that throws the following exception :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3", local:"ODM"). Expected elements are <{http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3}Study>
```

Any ideas?

Many Thanks

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For root tag `<OMD>`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ODM")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ODMTag
{
   @XmlElement(name = "Study", namespace = "http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3")
   StudyTag study;
}
```

For child tag `<Study>`

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StudyTag 
{
   @XmlAttribute(name = "OID")
   String OID;

   @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3")
   MetaDataVersion MetaDataVersion;
}
```

For tag `<MetaDataVersion>`

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MetaDataVersion 
{
   @XmlAttribute(name = "OID")
   String OID;

   @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
   String name;

   /** 
    * all other elements
    */
}
```

Unmarshalling:

```
   ODMTag odm = JAXB.unmarshal(new File(...), ODMTag.class)
```

Comment: So you're saying that I can't skip ODMTag and StudyTag?

Comment: @AnthonyWebster you can, like in Blaise Doughan's answer. And you can like in my answer. All ways are possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a StAX `XMLStreamReader` on the XML.  Then you advance the `XMLStreamReader` to the `MetaDataVersion` element and unmarshal from there.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: That's great, thanks! I'm not quite sure how to set things up in order for ItemGroupREF pointing to ItemGroupDEF to resolve to Domains containing a list of ItemGroups though. Any pointers would be most appreciated!